# Trying to pass JSX as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

**UPDATE:**

Code actually works! Had a header blocking the content and thought it wasn't rendering properly. Sorry for the confusion!

---

I am trying to pass this simple `<p>` JSX tag as a prop to `Navigation` and then display it, but for some reason it's not working.

Here is my `App.js` file that passes a JSX element to Navigation:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation main={<p>Testing!@22</p>} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my `Navigation.js` file that should take the prop `main` and display it:

```js
const Navigation = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <main className={classes.content}>{props.main}</main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: Please [don't use images for displaying code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1763258).

Comment: What error are you getting? The code you provided works for me.

Comment: The code you provided is functional: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-swirles-slm8g?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried and it worked for me.

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-wescoff-vz451?file=/src/App.js

`App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import Navigation from "./Navigation";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation main={<p>Testing!@22</p>} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

`Navigation.js`

```
import React from "react";

const Navigation = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <main>{props.main}</main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add information in your props instead of whole html elements.And later just add your props into whatever html element u want like so. `main='Testing!@22'`
and then in navigation do `<p>{props.main}</p>` or have `const whateverNameYouWant = 'Testing!@22'` and then `main={whateverNameYouWant}`.
And it would be better for u to destructure it inside Navigation so u should do `const Navigation = ({main})`   and then u just do `<p>{main}</p>`

Answer (score -1):

You can pass your `<p>Testing</p>` as `<Navigation><p>Testing</p></Navigation>` and then in `Navigation` component you simply replace `props.main` with `props.children`

Comment: This doesn't address the question/scenario the OP is asking

Comment: It also doesn't consider if multiple jsx need to be passed as props to a component.

Comment: @98sean98 they can be wrapped using <> </> react fragment

Comment: @DominikMatis I'll clarify, multiple jsx may be used in different places within a component's render function.

Comment: Okay that seems reasonable